# How to change a variable in the component view inside the callback function of $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have been trying to pass the 'error' data returned from the ajax request to the 'this.state.errorMessage' and rendering it in the view.

```
let getListState = () => {
  return {
    requestState: InviteStore.getRequestState()
  };
}

@withStyles(styles)
class InvitePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {};
      this.state.errorMessage = "temp";
  }

  _onChange() {
    this.setState(getListState());
    this.state = {};
    console.log("REQ STATE : "+ InviteStore.getRequestState());
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    InviteStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
    console.log("EVENT STATE  :" + InviteStore.getRequestState());
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    InviteStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
    console.log("EVENT STATE UN :" + InviteStore.getRequestState());
  }

  getErrorMessage()
  {
    return this.state.errorMessage;
  }

  sendInvitation(e)
  {
     e.preventDefault();
      let email_address = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email_address).value.trim();
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email_address).value = '';
      console.log(email_address);
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      type: ApiRoutes.routes.subscribe.type,
      url: ApiRoutes.routes.subscribe.url,
      data: {email: email_address},
      success: function(response){
        self.setState("requestState", "success");
        self.setState("token", response.data.token);
      }
      })
       .fail(function(response) {

        var temp = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        self.state.errorMessage =  "error";
      });

  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className={classnames('InvitePage', this.props.type)}>
        <h1>Request Invitation</h1>

        <form onSubmit={this.sendInvitation.bind(this)}>
          <input name="email_address" type="text" ref="email_address" placeholder="Enter your email" />
          <button className="button primary">Submit</button>
          {this.getErrorMessage()}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InvitePage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your listener is set correctly (are you sure event is not missing ?   InviteStore.addChangeListener('change',this._onChange.bind(this)); for example);

Otherwise you are putting this.state to an empty object, that's why you can't access your state.

```
_onChange() {
    this.setState(getListState());
    //this.state = {}; delete this line, why this.state = {} ?
    console.log("REQ STATE : "+ InviteStore.getRequestState());
}
```

Hope it helps